# Mapping subtext to MUI stepper steps results in all subtext rendered under each step

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using an MUI stepper to display the current status of a document.  I want to display some subtext under each status in the stepper to describe what should have been done by the time a status is complete/met.

I am having trouble displaying just one piece of subtext under each status.  My code results in all of my subtext being displayed under each status.

The array `extra` contains the text I want to display under each status in the `steps` array.

```
export default function IntakeStatusBar(props) {
    const { status } = props;
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
    const steps = ["New", "In Progress", "Completed", "Finalized", "Budget Approved", "In Plan"];
    const extra = [
        "Intake details have been entered.",
        "Estimations and questionnaires are completed.",
        "Estimation answers have been reviewed and validated.",
        "Approved intakes are collected.",
        "Approved intakes are reviewed and priortized by Admin.",
        "Approved intakes are approved for execution.",
    ];

    useEffect(() => {
        if (status === "In Progress") {
            setActiveStep(1);
        } else if (status === "Completed") {
            setActiveStep(2);
        } else if (status === "Finalized") {
            setActiveStep(3);
        } else if (status === "Budget Approved") {
            setActiveStep(4);
        } else if (status === "In Plan") {
            setActiveStep(5);
        } else setActiveStep(0);
    }, [status, activeStep]);

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={activeStep} connector={<QontoConnector />}>
                {steps.map((label) => {
                    return (
                        <Step key={label}>
                            <StepLabel StepIconComponent={QontoStepIcon}>
                                {label}
                                <br />
                                {extra.map((extraText) => {
                                    return <Typography>{extraText}</Typography>;
                                })}
                            </StepLabel>
                        </Step>
                    );
                })}
            </Stepper>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an Index to `steps.map` and `extra.map` and then a check to see if they match fixed this.

```
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={activeStep} connector={<QontoConnector />}>
            {steps.map((label, labelIndex) => {
                return (
                    <Step key={label}>
                        <StepLabel StepIconComponent={QontoStepIcon}>
                            {label}
                            <br />
                            {extra.map((extraText, extraTextIndex) => {
                                if (labelIndex === extraTextIndex) {
                                    return <Typography>{extraText}</Typography>;
                                } else return null;
                            })}
                        </StepLabel>
                    </Step>
                );
            })}
        </Stepper>
    </div>
);
```